# Connecting to 3G Modem with Command Line

Tags: command-line, networking, internet, 3g

I have a 3g Modem and it's my only way to connect to internet .

In the GUI Mode it's easy to connect via Network Manager, But how to connect to internet with this modem in the Text Mode?

Comment: Nice question, I need to know, too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[nmcli](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/en/man1/nmcli.1.html)

Comment: `nmcli con up id <id> &` or
`nmcli con up uuid <uuid> &`

thanks that is .

Comment: This is a weird answer... Mind explaining what the answer is?

Comment: I rather like my one-word answer :), but sure: nmcli a command line client for the Network Manager daemon.

Answer (score 1):

I  use `wvdial` to connect to my 3G modem as below:

1. install wvdial :

   ```
   sudo apt-get install wvdial
   ```
2. edit the `wvdial.conf` file by any text editor say `gedit` by below command:

   ```
   sudo gedit /etc/wvdial.conf
   ```
3. copy paste the following lines in wvdial.conf

   ```
   [Dialer a]
   Modem Type = Analog Modem
   Phone = *99#
   ISDN = 0
   Baud = 460800
   Username = " "
   Password = " "
   Modem = /dev/ttyUSB0
   Init1 = ATZ
   Init2 = at+cgdcont=1,"ip","your apn"
   Stupid Mode = 1
   ```

4 connect using ( you can change the name as you want by replacing a in above `wvdial.conf` )

```
 wvdial a
```

(just add apn according to isp you are using like aircelgprs for aircel, bsnnet for bsnl etc.  in `wvial.conf` file in place of "your apn")

Comment: I've been looking after this for two hours. Raspbian working with Huawei 3531 HSPA+ & Freedompop just changing "your apn" for freedompop.foggmobile.com" and editing this file:  
`#/etc/ppp/peers/wvdial  
noauth  
name wvdial  
# uncomment usepeerdns if you want to use your carriers dns server.  # Leave commented if you are using google dns 8.8.8.8/8.8.4.4 or other publicly available dns servers  
#usepeerdns  
defaultroute  
replacedefaultroute`

Answer (score 0):

[nmtui](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/nmtui.1.html)

It is a very basic UI for Network Manager. More convenient than "nmcli" IMHO.

Comment: Oops didn't realise the question was asked in 2012 ...

Comment: There is no problem answering to an old post. More ways to solve a problem are always good and new software might have been developed since the question was asked.