# Ubuntu server auto connect to any random 3G USB (netstick)

Tags: 14.04, internet

I have a kiosk running on Ubuntu Server 14.04.3 which currently accepts a LAN cable as an internet source.

What I want to do is to let it receive internet also from a 3G USB (netstick). I started looking around the web for that and it seems that I need to know exactly which Internet provider is it and the modem. Unfortunately I can't know that since anyone may come and connect their own netstick. I was looking for a way to simply accept all netsticks regardless of the Internet provider etc.

Is it possible that whenever I connect a netstick to the computer it will be auto detected and I will have Internet connection while not knowing ahead of time what netstick I'm going to plug in?

Comment: I've used one from Verizon and one from US Cellular and not had any major issues. One caveat: http://askubuntu.com/questions/577166/ubuntu-14-04-mounts-a-3g-modem-as-usb-storage The good news is that you can probably return one if you can't get it to work but I've never found one that didn't "just work" (pretty much) for me. That link is the only thing I've ever had to do and I only had to do it with the one from Verizon.

Comment: I think the most straightforward way is to run a script on detection of any USB to: 1. check if it's a netstick; 2. try to determine the internet provider; 3. run the command specific to the determined internet provider. Of course, the major obstacle being if the internet provider can be determined in the first place. What netstick utility are you looking at? I'm unfamiliar with netstick operation on Ubuntu.

Comment: You might also take a look at [`nmcli`](http://askubuntu.com/a/94121) to see if it can connect with just `id` or `uuid` mentioned in the comment. If it can, we can skip the internet provider dtermination step on the hypothetical script.